# how can i use sapply and bind_rows without importing the file extension?

Tags: r, list, gsub, sapply

Hi sorry for the newbie question but I've been struggling with something simple and cant work it out...
I need to import multiple .csv files from a folder and combine them all using bind_rows such that the name of the original file is attributed to the appropriate set of data, with name as 'id' in the first column. It is working just fine except I cant get rid of the .csv file extension! so frustrating. Is there something I'm missing with this code? Thanks for your help.

```
#Create file paths to read in multiple water level spreadsheets
fileNames <- list.files(path="N:\\Projects and project proposals\\water level", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE) 
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.csv')
file.list  <- gsub(pattern = "$.csv", "", file.list)
df.list <- sapply(file.list, read.csv, simplify=FALSE)
df <- bind_rows(df.list, .id = "id")
```

Comment: Your `gsub` is a bit off. You need to pass in the fill name so you `sapply` so don't remove the extension to soon. After you bind rows, then you can remove the extension from the name: `df$id  <- gsub(pattern = "\\.csv$", "",df$id)`

Comment: that worked, thanks so much!!